# How to change the Django date time format in a string

Tags: python, django

Given a long string (serialized Django object) how can we search all the timestamps and replace them with the correct format (dd/mm/YYYY HH:MM)

Example date (from the given example): `2022-01-11T16:49:43.897`
Desired date time format: `11/01/2022 16:49`

What I've tried so far:

```
@login_required
def my_view(request):
    response = dict()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        files = Files.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
        for fhr in files:
            fhr.updated = fhr.updated.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        data = serialize("json", files)
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
    return HttpResponse('')
```

Basically I tried to edit the queryset with the correct format `strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")` so that when I serialize the QuerySet into JSON data `data = serialize("json", files)` the string (`data`) contains the date and time in the correct format but it did not work.

So now I think that the only chance is to edit directly the string and replace those timestamps with the timestamps in the correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to specify encoder class in serialize function. Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json).

```
import typing

from datetime import datetime
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder


class DatetimeJSONEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):

    def default(self, o: typing.Any) -> str:
        result = super().default(o)
        if isinstance(o, datetime):
            result = o.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        return result

data = serialize("json", files, cls=DatetimeJSONEncoder)
```

Comment: Thank you, looks promising however I am getting this error:

`if isinstance(o, datetime):
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types`

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention that datetime is a class from datetime module, edited the answer.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you!